# *** Assertion failure in -[id<MKAnnotationView> layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776

Tags: objective-c, backwards-compatibility, ios6.1

I get a crash when executing my app on iOS 6.1.: I must have modified something I was not aware of and when I tried to execute the app on the iPod touch of my mum I got that crash and that happens even on the simulator with that version. What could it be and what may I do to fix it so that the app works both on iOS6 and iOS7?

Thanks,

Comment: Give more details of the exception, stack trace, what line of your code it is thrown on.

Comment: The error seems to happen in the UIView support rather than in my code. I have no cue about the part of my code that calls that function, of course that is not part of my code. How would I get rid of that call, perhaps introduced in the iOS 7 support, when I execute my code on iOS 6.1? Thanks

Comment: Unknown - add the exception stack trace to the question. Something to do with auto-layout possibly...